# Построение трехмерного облака точек

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно построить такое же трехмерное облако точек синего цвета на python?
Проблема в алгоритме создания точек.
Как сгенерировать такие же точки для их последующего отображения?
Под такими же я подразумеваю трехмерное круглое сечение с рандомными прерываниями.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.html

Comment: Вопрос именно в алгоритме построения координат

Comment: Ну так в примере CrazyElf есть алгоритм построения координат.

Comment: Алгоритм построения координат трехмерного круглого сечения. Т.е. вопрос состоит в том, как сформировать такое же облако точек как на изображении.

Comment: Вы отредактируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы сразу было понятно, что именно вам нужно

Comment: Не понятен вопрос от слова вообще, что вам нужно ? алгоритм построения 3d графиков ? получить формулу для такого же графика как на рисунке ? если да то там видна только часть чего то, давайте тогда полную картинку если хотите помощи, ваш вопрос не согласуется с тем что вы в комментариях отвечаете, определитесь что вам нужно

Comment: Внес исправления в вопрос. Меня интересует именно эта часть картинки. Круглое сечение и облако точек. Как можно получить такое же облако точек?

Comment: А где на картинке вы видите сечение ? что в вашем понимании сечение ?

Comment: Я считаю, что оранжевая линия проходит по круглому сечению синего облака точек

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d


np.random.seed(16)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d');

x = 2*np.random.random(100) - 1
y = x + np.random.randn(100) * 0.2
z = np.sqrt(3 - (x**2 + y**2))

ax.plot3D(np.sort(x), np.sort(y), np.sqrt(3 - (np.sort(x)**2 + np.sort(y)**2)), 'orange')
ax.scatter3D(x, y, z);
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По поводу трубы, трубу можно по разному нарисовать, ну например с помощью квадратичной формы

```
np.random.seed(16)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d');

x = 2*np.random.random(500) - 1
y = x + np.random.randn(500) * 200
z = x**2 - y**2 + x*y

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c='blue');
ax.scatter3D(x, y, -(z + 300000), c='blue');
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Представим, что есть металлическая труба, вот как бы я мог ее изобразить в виде облака точек?
Ваш ответ мне помог, но не дал конечного решения моего вопроса. Не могли бы вы помочь?

Comment: @Mark Twain обновил ответ, по трубе )

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Это именно то, что нужно!